# How to Access/Download OneNote notebook with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, onenote, onenote-api

How do I access a OneNote notebook using Python? Is there a way to export it to a `pdf` or other file programmatically? The notes are taken by hand, so I unfortunately can't just parse it for text.

I've found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2011/06/16/onenote-amp-python-using-onenote-com-api-with-python.aspx) from 2011, but the links are dead and I imagine it would be outdated anyway. I've also found [this GitHub](https://github.com/varunsrin/one-py) but I don't see how to implement it to do what I want.

Alternatively, is there another language I could use?

Answer (score 5):

If your notebooks are stored in OneDrive or Office 365, you can use the OneNote APIs to access them.  Information about the APIs are on http://dev.onenote.com/.

For sample code, check out https://github.com/onenotedev/. There is sample code (in C# and other languages) that allows you to access pages in Notebooks.