# Is there anyway to read .one(OneNote files) using Python script?

Tags: python, onenote, onenote-api

I am trying to read .one file(OneNote files) and want to write its content into a text file, but didn't find a single way to do it using Python. Please help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622471/how-to-access-download-onenote-notebook-with-python

Comment: @JorgeLavín am able to fetch OneNote into my local but not able to read its content.By looking at API didn't find a way to read. Please suggest any possible solution.

Comment: one note contains not just text, they have many other formatted contents. so do you really only need the text in it?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't Python, but for other internet voyagers trying to escape Microsoft's iron grip this PowerShell script is pure magic.

https://passbe.com/2019/bulk-export-onenote-2013-2016-pages-as-html/

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the content of your notes calling:

```
./me/onenote/pages/1-1c13bcbae2fdd747a95b3e5386caddf1!1-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/content?includeIDs=true&includeInkML=true&preAuthenticated=true
```

It will give you text/html, which you can parse with https://pypi.org/project/lxml/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a good way to decode .one file.
But I find another way to workaround it.

1. Install OneNote 2016 and sync the contents.
2. Install the Evernote legacy version
3. Import data from OneNote to Evernote. (There's a button on GUI).
4. Export notes to html from Evernote.
5. Then you can do whatever you want. Yeah!